# Control where a redirect goes after failed validation

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to set the redirect path should a request fail validation in Laravel 7? Example:

```
public function handleForm(Request $request)
{
  if (! $request->validate(['someData' => 'required|size:12|alpha_num'])) {
    return redirect(...);
  }
}
```

In this particular case, if `someData` doesn't validate, Laravel redirects me to the path the request originally came from. This is not the behavior I want to see. I would like to be able to define a different path to redirect to. Is that possible?

Comment: `validate()` has a built-in redirect. Check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Laravel Validation's `fails()` method to check if it fails, then redirect on which route you desired.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'someData' => 'required|size:12|alpha_num',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect(...);
}
```

[documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation)